# Mostrar registro do BD sem refresh

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax, json

```
// esta é uma pagina separada, chamada adicionar_consulta.php 
<?php
$conexao = new mysqli("localhost","root","","hospital"); 

if ($conexao->connect_errno) {
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $conexao->connect_errno . ") " . 
$conexao->connect_error;
}


$res = $conexao->query("SELECT nome,idade 
                    FROM paciente, ficha_atendimento 
                    WHERE paciente.id = ficha_atendimento.id_paciente 
                    AND ficha_atendimento.id IN (SELECT MIN(id) FROM 
ficha_atendimento)
                    AND ficha_atendimento.status IS TRUE");

while ($row = $res->fetch_assoc()) {

echo " id = " . $row['nome'] . "  " . $row['idade']. "</br>";
}

?>
```

Quero mostrar os dados dessa consulta em PHP na mesma página onde está o botão que faz a chamada.
Este código acima é o script da consulta. Ao apertar o botão ela é realizada, mas ocorre um redirect para outra página.

Comment: Comece por colocar a página que chama essa consulta...

Answer (score 3):

**Utilizando ajax**

Na sua página onde tem o botão, introduza o seguinte código:

```
   $("#idDoBotao").click(function(){
   $.ajax({
       url:"adicionar_consulta.php ",
       type:"POST",
       data: ({}), //Como não está enviando nenhuma informação, pode deixar vazio
        success:function(resposta){
           $('#resultado').html(resposta);
        }

           });
            });
```

## Considerações

Estou considerando que seu ***botão*** tem o **id `"idDoBotao"`** e que você tem uma ***div*** com o **id `"resultado"`**

---

## Funcionamento

Ao clicar no botão com ***id "idDoBotao"*** ele executará a função com o ajax. Após executar o seu código php (e obter sucesso) ele escreverá o resultado na sua div com ***id "resultado***

---

## Passar parâmetros no ajax

Se você quer enviar algum valor por formulário, você pode pegar esse valor!
Vamos supor que eu tenha a seguinte input: `<input type="text" name="valor" value="foo" />`
O procedimento no código seria o seguinte:

```
   $("#idDoBotao").click(function(){
   $.ajax({
       url:"adicionar_consulta.php ",
       type:"POST",
       data: ({valor:$("input[name='valor']").val()}), //estamos enviando o valor do input
        success:function(resposta){
           $('#resultado').html(resposta);
        }

           });
            });
```

E é claro, que precisaríamos pegar esse valor no php:

```
$valor = $_POST['valor']; 
echo $valor; // retornará "foo"
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
$.ajax({
   type: 'POST',
   URL: 'urlDoSeuPHP',
   data: {
      // valores a ser passado
   },
   success: function(data){
      // Aqui voce trata o retorno
   }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -2):

Melhor jeito de fazer isso é com Ajax. Tem bastante tutorial na internet, e você pode simplificar usando o Ajax do jQuery. Dá uma olhadinha aqui: https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_load.asp

Pra facilitar, é legal que a tua página de consulta já traga o resultado formatado em HTML, e aí você só insere numa  com id específico. O site que eu passei é bem didático, mas você encontra muita informação sobre Ajax e jQuery na internet. Boa sorte!